# Populating feature class attribute field with input from another table using ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4 and its ModelBuilder

I would like to add an attribute value from one feature class to another using ModelBuilder.

Is there a geoprocessing tool that will directly populate a record?

I have one watershed and several tables I would like to extract data from.  I'm just beginning ModelBuilder and very new to Python.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the table you wish to use to populate the feature class with? Are these spatial (do they have a spatial component?), is there a key field or a common field between the tables ie - does one table have a field that is identical to the other like a watershed ID? Both of these scenarios require different tools to perform the actions - Spatial Join vs. Table Join. Please can you update the question with this information.

Comment: I wish to populate the Watershed polygon FC with data from a polyline FC and a Zonal Statistics table.  As you ask the question, I think a table join may be the solution.  Everything I've tried in Model Builder outputs a separate table, but I may have neglected to try a standard join.  I will try to populate the tables with a common field and try join.

Comment: Doing something in place in the model builder may not be possible. I think most Tools in the Toolbox will create a new table / feature. But update this question as you get new information.